# Change equation size only in \begin{equation} mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I am a teacher writing lecture notes. I would like to have equations big in this document while keeping text math (betwen $$) at the text size.

Is there any way to properly do it? All methods I've found yet change the form of the equation (move the equal sign with respect to fraction bar...etc). This is not suitable at all.

Using "DeclareMathSizes" change size in the two modes [some math] and $some math$ together. Not suitable too.

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: Try something like `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\large}`. But you'll have to write it for each display style math environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually this works but the equation is slightly changed. For exemple, in the equation \[v=\frac{d}{t} \], the equal sign gets bigger and bigger compared to letters as you increase the size. Moreover the equal sign is also slightly shifted up with respect to the ratio bar.